# "Multiple markers at this line" error at constructor

Tags: java

So I am using gpdraw as a library to draw stuff for my computer science class, and I'm trying to run this in Eclipse and I put the main method but I'm still getting errors.

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class House {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        private DrawingTool myPencil;
        private SketchPad myPaper;

        public House() {
            myPaper = new SketchPad(500, 500);

            myPencil = new DrawingTool(myPaper);
        }

        public void draw() {
            myPencil.up();
            myPencil.turnRight(90);
            myPencil.forward(20);
            myPencil.turnLeft(90);
            myPencil.forward(20);
            myPencil.turnRight(20);
            myPencil.forward(200);
        }

    }  

}
```

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: I mean, what type or errors? The name of the errors that you are getting.

Comment: "Multiple markers at this line" on public House()

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to stuff everything into the `main` method. That won't work. Instead, have `main` call `draw` (on an *instance* of the class, a context which a static method does not have available) and *define* everything in the class, not a method.

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class House {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        House instance = new House();
        instance.draw();
    }

    private DrawingTool myPencil;
    private SketchPad myPaper;

    public House() {
        myPaper = new SketchPad(500, 500);
        myPencil = new DrawingTool(myPaper);
    }

    public void draw() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @frosty: Happens to the best of us. By the way, I hope my brief mention of static vs instance members was enlightening, or at least not further confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not allow nesting methods and/or constructors.

You need something like this:

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class House {

    private DrawingTool myPencil;
    private SketchPad myPaper;

    public House() {
        myPaper = new SketchPad(500, 500);
        myPencil = new DrawingTool(myPaper);
    }

    public void draw() {
        myPencil.up();
        myPencil.turnRight(90);
        myPencil.forward(20);
        myPencil.turnLeft(90);
        myPencil.forward(20);
        myPencil.turnRight(20);
        myPencil.forward(200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // whatever

    }   
}
```

Comment: Happens even to the best of us.